# How to remove app from itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I submitted a brand new app to AppStore and it got rejected. ... (nothing new there). What I want to do is delete that app completely from my itunesconnect account. I don't know what apple recently changed but in the past once the app was rejected I use to see a "delete" button on the summary page. Now I don't see one anymore.

Comment: @PowHu now itunes not provide this functionality of delete app in more tab .

Comment: @PowHu iTunes has changed, now More > Delete App no longer available

Comment: @TapasPal my app status is rejected, Then how to remove from itunes

Answer (score 1):

From the [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

> If you’ve created an app in iTunes Connect that you no longer need to
>   manage, you can delete it from iTunes Connect.
>
> **Apps can’t be deleted if they are part of a Game Center group**, in an
>   app bundle, or currently displayed on a store. You’ll want to remove
>   the app from sale or from the group if you want to delete it. See
>    [Removing an App from Sale](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW17) or [Removing an App from a Group](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectGameCenter_Guide/Groups/Groups.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013726-CH4-SW2). Apps that
>   have not been approved yet can’t be deleted; instead, reject the app.
>   See [Removing Your Binary from Review](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW34).

Answer (score 1):

Simple steps for Deleting/Removing app from iTunes Connect:

Just Use this steps Below ->

iTunesConnect > App > Rights and Pricing > specific stores > Deselect All > Save

After 24hours app will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Although, as [Tapas Pal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29294096/6286781) pointed out from the Apple doc, you can't delete an app that hasn't been submitted, you **can** use that app ID for something else later.  That's what I did:

1. Renamed the app so I could easily see that it was in limbo, eg. "FUTURE DEVELOPMENT".
2. When I had a new app, that stub was ready for me to use.

Hope that helps.